# SIRD model fitting in R using real data not working

Tags: r, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit SIRD model in R to real data. However, the observed values are lying nowhere on the fitted curve. I can't understand what the error is or how to resolve it, but I have noticed that changing the value of "state" produces  the error

```
 DLSODA-  Warning..Internal T (=R1) and H (=R2) are
          such that in the machine, T + H = T on the next step  
         (H = step size). Solver will continue anyway.
    In above message, R1 = 0.1, R2 = 9.94667e-21
```

Here is my entire code. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
library(deSolve)
state<-c(S=10000,I=1000,R=5000,D=100)
parameters <- c(a=180,b=0.4,g=0.2)
eqn<-function(t, state, parameters) {
  with(as.list(c(state, parameters)),{
    dS <- -a*I*S
    dI <- a*I*S-g*I-b*I
    dR <- g*I
    dD <-b*I
    list(c(dS,dI,dR,dD))
  }) 
}
times <- seq(0.1,2.6,by=0.1)
out <- ode(y = state, times = times, func = eqn, parms = parameters)
out
plot(out)

library(FME)
data <- data.frame(
  time = seq(0.1,2.6,0.1),
  S=c(11417747943,11417733626,11417717809,11417702207,11417685587,11417670536,
      11417652672,11417629493,11417603660,11417577979,11417550853,11417520318,
      11417495673,11417466974,11417435119,11417399167,11417362265,11417326539,
      11417286125,11417254482,11417226564,11417187020,11417143837,11417095924,
      11417046477,11416989403),
  I=c(3686,7062,4415,8040,7706,4316,8266,13947,13593,11207,13446,19114,5121,15400,
      16658,15386,19766,21024,22426,10683,3958,15701,10290,23299,11340,29331),
  R=c(9913,7193,11344,7467,8861,10671,9510,9138,12174,14400,13588,11314,19463,13165,
      15098,20444,17019,14523,17874,20854,23820,23600,32641,24126,37821,27508),
  D=c(54,57,56,88,50,48,87,84,58,70,92,99,58,132,95,111,112,166,108,102,139,
      227,249,481,277,222)
)

cost <- function(p) {
    out <- ode(state, times, eqn, p)
    modCost(out, data, weight = "none") 
}

fit <- modFit(f = cost, p = parameters)
summary(fit)
  
out1 <- ode(state, times, eqn, parameters)
out2 <- ode(state, times, eqn, coef(fit))
plot(out1, out2, obs=data, obspar=list(pch=16, col="red"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has several issues:

1. the order of magnitude of state variables differs, so you need `weight="std"` or `weight = "mean"`
2. the initial values of the state variables are far away. This is the most critical error. You may either set it manually to a reasonable value (see below) or even better, fit it, see FME documentation how this can be done.
3. Start parameters are far away from optimum. While it is desirable that the algorithm converges to an optimum from arbitrary naive start values, this is rarely the case. Therefore, some careful consideration or trial and error is unavoidable.
4. The mass balance is violated, i.e. the sum of all 4 states changes over time. Check `rowSums(data[-1])`.

Here an approach that handles parts of the problem. The next step would then be to fix the mass balance and to include the ode initial states of the ode model as parameters of the nonlinear optimization.

```
library(deSolve)
library(FME)


eqn<-function(t, state, parameters) {
  with(as.list(c(state, parameters)),{
    dS <- -a*I*S
    dI <-  a*I*S - g*I - b*I
    dR <-  g*I
    dD <-  b*I
    list(c(dS,dI,dR,dD))
  }) 
}

data <- data.frame(
  time = seq(0.1,2.6,0.1),
  S=c(11417747943,11417733626,11417717809,11417702207,11417685587,11417670536,
      11417652672,11417629493,11417603660,11417577979,11417550853,11417520318,
      11417495673,11417466974,11417435119,11417399167,11417362265,11417326539,
      11417286125,11417254482,11417226564,11417187020,11417143837,11417095924,
      11417046477,11416989403),
  I=c(3686,7062,4415,8040,7706,4316,8266,13947,13593,11207,13446,19114,5121,15400,
      16658,15386,19766,21024,22426,10683,3958,15701,10290,23299,11340,29331),
  R=c(9913,7193,11344,7467,8861,10671,9510,9138,12174,14400,13588,11314,19463,13165,
      15098,20444,17019,14523,17874,20854,23820,23600,32641,24126,37821,27508),
  D=c(54,57,56,88,50,48,87,84,58,70,92,99,58,132,95,111,112,166,108,102,139,
      227,249,481,277,222)
)

state <- c(S=11417747943, I=5000, R=8000, D=50)
parameters <- c(a=1e-10, b=0.001, g=0.1)
times<-seq(0.1,2.6,by=0.01)

cost <- function(p) {
    out <- ode(state, times, eqn, p)
    modCost(out, data, weight = "mean") 
}

fit <- modFit(f = cost, p = parameters)
summary(fit, corr=TRUE)
  
out2 <- ode(state, times, eqn, coef(fit))
plot(out2, obs=data, obspar=list(pch=16, col="red"), ylim=list(c(0, 2e10), c(0, 50000), c(0, 50000), c(0, 600)))
```

### Edit

The following approach improves the fit by:

1. fixing mass balance by setting total population to be constant over time
2. re-scale data to improve stability of optimization
3. guessing initial values from data

It would (in theory) be even better to include initial values in the optimization, but this would lead again to non-identifiability of parameters
due to the intrinsic characteristics of the given model and data. See [twocomp_final.R](http://desolve.r-forge.r-project.org/user2014/examples/FME/fit_twocomp.svg) for a related tutorial example.

Instead of data rescaling, one may also consider to adapt control parameters
of the optimizer(s) and of the `ode` function, or to rescale individual state variables differently.
However, it is easiest here just to rescale the population to "million people".

```
## fix mass balance, i.e. make sum of all states constant
## an alternative would be an additional process in the model
## for migration and / or birth and natural death
Population  <- rowSums(data[c("S", "I", "R", "D")])
data$S      <- Population[1] - rowSums(data[c("I", "R", "D")])

## rescale state variables to numerically more convenient numbers
## here simply: million people
scaled_data <- cbind(
  time = data$time,
  data[c("S", "I", "R", "D")] * 1e-6
)

## guess initial values from data (of course a little bit subjective)
state <- c(
  S = scaled_data$S[1], 
  I = mean(scaled_data$I[1:3]), 
  R = mean(scaled_data$R[1:5]), 
  D = mean(scaled_data$D[1:3])
)

## use good initial parameters by thinking and some trial and error
parameters <- c(a = 0.0001, b = 0.01, g = 1)

cost2 <- function(p) {
  out <- ode(state, times, eqn, p)
  modCost(out, scaled_data, weight = "mean")
}

## fit model, enable trace with option nprint
fit <- modFit(f = cost2, p = parameters, control = list(nprint = 1))
summary(fit, corr=TRUE)

out2 <- ode(state, times, eqn, coef(fit))
plot(out2, obs = scaled_data, obspar = list(pch = 16, col = "red"))
```

[image: Model fit]

Comment: Your code has given me the desired graphs. However, errors still remain: Error in cov2cor(x$cov.unscaled) : 'V' is not a square numeric matrix
In addition: Warning message:
In summary.modFit(fit, corr = TRUE) :
  Cannot estimate covariance; system is singular". I have been trying to fix it for the last 10 days, but did not succeed. Any ideas?

Comment: This indicates non-identifiability of parameters. Have you tried to correct your mass balance?

Comment: An improved approach was included in the above solution see **Edit**.